# Archive log transfer from Oracle 9i to Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, archive, data-transfer

I have a situation where I need to transfer Oracle 9i archive logs to an Oracle 10g database, from where they are to be mined by a log-miner and then used by an Oracle streams capture/apply processes.

(Oracle 9 archive logs can be read by the Oracle 10 logminer - I can manually copy the archive logs across, manually register them and have them mined, captured then applied).

The difficulty is that the way Oracle does archive log transfer changed quite a bit between 9i and 10g and setting up the 9i database to transfer to the remote machine like so:

```
log_archive_dest_state_2 = enable
log_archive_dest_2 = "service=OTHERMACHINE arch optional"
```

no longer works.

I get this in the 9i logs:

```
*** 2009-05-22 04:03:44.149
RFS network connection lost at host 'OTHERMACHINE'
Error 3113 attaching RFS server to standby instance at host 'OTHERMACHINE'
Error 3113 attaching to destination LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2 standby host 'OTHERMACHINE'
Heartbeat failed to connect to standby 'OTHERMACHINE'. Error is 3113.
*** 2009-05-22 04:03:44.150
kcrrfail: dest:2 err:3113 force:0
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
```

And in the 10g log I get:

```
Fri May 22 04:07:42 2009
WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)
```

My question is:

Does anyone know how I could configure my 9i or 10g server such that the 10g server will accept the 9i connection in such a way that I can transfer the 9i archive logs to the 10g server. It would be a bonus if the archive logs would be automatically registered in the 10g server.

Note I have not set up a full DataGuard configuration here and the 10g database is not a secondary server.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit**

Note that I can log on to the 10g server from the 9i server via sqlplus, so connectivity is not the problem

**Edit 2**

After a large amount of time searching for a solution, I've finally decided that such a mechanism doesn't work, and that a non-Oracle method of transferring archive logs from 9i to 10g will need to be used (e.g. rsync).

Comment: Can you reach the 10g server from the 9i server via a dblink?

Comment: Alternately, try a tnsping from the 9i:
tnsping OTHERMACHINE

Comment: I can tnsping and reach the other machine via a DB link and sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

Are your databases current with patches?

Also, do your connections typically take a while to authenticate? After V10.1, the default SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT is set to 60 seconds. Prior to that version it defaults to indefinite.

Ref Metalink 345197.1: Connections that Used to Work in Oracle 10.1 Now Intermittently Fail with ORA-3113,ORA-3106 or ORA-3136 in 10.2